# macOS Monterey - Install Scipy Error "No lapack/blas resources found"

Tags: python-3.x, macos, scipy, lapack, openblas

I have installed pyenv on Mac using `brew install pyenv`. I want to run a python project which requires installation of `scipy==1.5.4`. I tried installing it using the command `pip3 install scipy==1.5.4` but I got an error `No lapack/blas resources found`.

To solve that I ran the following commands as suggested in the error and other solutions.

`brew install openblas`

Followed by:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openblas/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Next I did

```
brew install lapack
```

Followed by

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/lapack/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/lapack/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Now that I've installed both `blas` and `lapack` I expected the error to go away but I am still facing similar error. How can I solve this?

PS

**Complete Error**

```
    Running from SciPy source directory.
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    openblas_clapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_3_10_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    atlas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8dln98w/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['/Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8dln98w/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    /private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8dln98w/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:624: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-install-x19xcozn/scipy/setup.py", line 583, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-install-x19xcozn/scipy/setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-build-env-n8dln98w/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "/private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-install-x19xcozn/scipy/setup.py", line 477, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError(msg)
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found. Note: Accelerate is no longer supported.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-install-x19xcozn/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-record-uy6kggfm/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/furqan/.pyenv/versions/3.6.13/envs/venv/include/site/python3.6/scipy" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8p/qhqd9mgj7n93g_6snx_4y9rh0000gn/T/pip-install-x19xcozn/scipy/
```

Comment: I suggest you try `conda`. In particular, if you are using a Apple Silicon-based machine, you can use miniforge: https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge

Answer (score 9):

We had a similar issue when upgrading a Django app to use Python 3.8. The solution for us came out of [this github thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4564#issuecomment-865077698). We're running on Big Sur so not sure if the same fix would work for you, but before you run your package install run `export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1`. Again, not sure if this will solve in your context, but it worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on MacBookAir (M1 2020) right now and this command worked for me:

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```